# How to avoid TypeScript modules resolving from parent directories of the project instead of node_modules?

Tags: typescript

I have a module that is installed in `node_modules`, and want to import a file from it.

I also have a locally installed version of this module in a parent directory to the one where my project is.

For some reason, when I do `import { something } from 'my-module/myFile'`, it actually resolves it not by going in `node_modules`, but by taking my local version of that module that is stored somewhere else in my machine, in a parent directory.

Why does TypeScript resolves modules outside of the directory it's being built in? How could it even find my module outside of its own folder and not just find it in node modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with ECMAScript 2015, JavaScript has a concept of modules. TypeScript shares this concept.

Modules import one another using a module loader. At runtime the module loader is responsible for locating and executing all dependencies of a module before executing it. Well-known modules loaders used in JavaScript are the CommonJS module loader for Node.js and require.js for Web applications.

You mention `node_modules` so I'm guessing you are using Node.js. `"moduleResolution": "node"` in your tsconfig.json file.

From Node.js [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders):

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a core module, and
> does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then Node.js starts at the
> parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and
> attempts to load the module from that location. Node will not append
> node_modules to a path already ending in node_modules.

And for [file modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules):

> If the exact filename is not found, then Node.js will attempt to load
> the required filename with the added extensions: .js, .json, and
> finally .node.
>
> TypeScript overlays the TypeScript source file extensions (.ts, .tsx,
> and .d.ts) over the Node’s resolution logic.

Make sure that you are using it correctly.

Comment: I accepted this answer but would just like to add for whoever ends up reading this, that the confusing bit is that TypeScript won't care about what's in `main` inside the `package.json` file. This is used to load built JavaScript file, but if your module is in uncompiled TypeScript, the solution is to have an `index.ts` file at the root of the module folder. This is explained in more detail in [another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320632/how-to-import-an-npm-module-that-has-a-typescript-main-file-in-typescript).

Comment: @Liana Pigeot did you try 'types' instead 'main' in your 'package.json'?

Comment: I did try it, but it didn't seem to work when I tried.The only way I managed to get it working was having an index.ts at the root, which is apparently what TypeScript looks for by default.

Answer (score 1):

When you import from npm, you can't import by a file name (unless you write the full path starting with ./node_modules... don't), only by package. It doesn't find one so it falls back to looking for a local file instead.

So assuming you have an actual package `my-module` in node_modules which has an entry point (main in package.json), which says `export something`, then `import {something} from 'my-module'` should do the trick.

Comment: Importing by filename is legal. From Node.js docs: "If the exact filename is not found, then Node.js will attempt to load the required filename with the added extensions: .js, .json, and finally .node."

Comment: Sure it's, as said the path would need to start with ./node_modules in that case, all i mean it's not a very good idea to force that on users if you're making a reusable module.

Comment: Indeed it did work importing from `../node_modules`, which is what I'm doing at the moment, but I'd like to properly import the npm package. However I haven't found any way that actually works. I posted a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320632/how-to-import-an-npm-module-that-has-a-typescript-main-file-in-typescript) about how to actually load the main typescript file of an npm module as it doesn't seem possible from what I've tried...