# How to import an npm module that has a Typescript main file in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I can't figure out what's the proper way of importing a Typescript npm module.

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

**module package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "main": "src/myModule.ts"
}
```

**module src/myModule.ts**

```
export module MyModule {
  // Code inside
}
```

**code using the npm module**

```
import { MyModule } from 'my-module'; // Doesn't work
import { MyModule } = require('my-module'); // Doesn't work.
```

The module is installed as a dependency in the package.json, and for example I can do

```
import { MyModule } from '../node_modules/my-module/src/myModule.ts';
```

But obviously this isn't great. What I want is a way to just import any exports that are in the main module file, but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: have you tried using import 'my-module/src/myModule' ??

Comment: Is this a node module? If you build it as npm package you can just create an `index.ts` in the root that exports the library. Then you can just do `import { MyModule } from 'MyModule'`

Comment: Yes, this actually worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 'main' in package.json is useful only to packaging tools like webpack or the build tool of angular-cli. It is used to select different bundles according to the user's needs: ES6, ES5, UMD...

TypeScript ignores that. You need to specify the file you want, exactly as if you were refering to your own project:

```
import { MyModule } from 'my-module/src/myModule';
```

What other libraries like Angular do is to create a barrel, a file usually called 'index.ts' or 'index.d.ts', that imports and exports all types in the library.

The advantage of this is that, if you create a index.d.ts file in the root of my-module:

```
export { MyModule } from './src/myModule';
// other exports
```

You can simply do this:

```
import {MyModule} from 'my-module'
```

As typescript, when importing from a folder, automatically uses a `index.ts` or `index.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 2):

You should use "types" property instead of "main" property with typescript modules. [How TypeScript resolves modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)